# Why does glGetUniformLocation report some of my uniform locations as -1?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I have been writing GLSL shaders for over a year but this is the first time I have run into this problem. I am on the iOS platform - if that matters.

In a vertex shader I have this:

```
uniform mediump mat4 projectionViewModelMatrix;
```

In a fragment shader I have been using for months I have the following uniforms:

```
uniform int channels;
uniform sampler2D hero;
```

Nothing to write home about. I added three additional uniforms to the fragment shader:

```
uniform int heroChannels;
uniform int heroWidth;
uniform int heroHeight;
```

Using

```
glGetUniformLocation
```

I tried to grab the location of all my uniforms. This is when my own personal hell began. This is the result:

```
uniform heroChannels location -1
uniform channels location 4
uniform hero location 5
uniform heroHeight location -1
uniform projectionViewModelMatrix location 0
uniform heroWidth location -1
```

Huh? Why are the recently added uniforms not given a valid location by the GL Gods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple things come to mind.

First, it's possible each of your int uniforms actually takes a whole vector in uniform space, and thus you may be running out of space - you can try to combine them into vectors to see if it helps.

Second, it's possible that the shader compiler happily discards the uniforms in case they're not actually in use. If this is the case, then they naturally won't get a location.

Comment: Jari, is there any way to force the compiler not to discard unused variables?

Comment: @dugla: The glUniform function family specifically does not error on location -1 to make situations like this work, as unused variables are fairly common with stitched shaders. Why worry about it?

Comment: Jari you nailed it. The newly added uniforms were indeed unused. Assigning them to int dev_null forced them to be recognized. Good catcht. Sigh, GL is such a pain. Cheers.

Comment: @Joe_Wreschnig, I am building a basic shader dictionary for an iOS app I am writing. My thought was to create an dictionary for each shader in my library with the uniforms and attributes as elements in the shader dictionary. Just a way to clean up some of the endless bookkeeping in GL.

Comment: @dugla: But you're doing more bookkeeping than necessary. Just store the glGetUniform returns, pass them back in to set the uniforms later, and you don't need to care if they're -1 or not.

Comment: @Joe_Wreschnig, not parsing your answer. My hack around rather dim GLSL compiler is to assign the currently unused uniforms to a local var in my frag shader - dev_null. This is needed to force a valid location returned from glGetUniformLocation. I store return values from glGetUniformLocation in my shader dictionary. Easy peasy. Storing -1 makes no sense. I am simply putting a thin layer of lightweight middleware between Cocoa Touch land and GL land.

Comment: @dugla: Why does storing -1 make no sense? (Or rather, why does it make less sense than storing the location of unused variables at all?) My point is that -1 _is_ a valid value for glUniform. Plus, your "solution" breaks as soon as you have a better optimizing compiler.

Comment: @Joe_Wreschnig: I assume he's planning to really use those new uniforms eventually, and was just confused about the compiler behavior before he did.

Comment: @Jari: Which seems like all the more reason not to care that they're -1, and not a reason to force the compiler not to optimize them out.

Comment: Dudes, chill. @Jari is correct. Just growin' some shader code here my friends. Unused vars a given. All is working now. Shader dictionary loveliness. Cheers.